# hive-exec gets into conflict with commons-lang3 in CDH 6.3.2 when generating a CSV file via Java Spark 2.4

Tags: apache-spark, hadoop, talend, cloudera-cdh, apache-commons-lang3

I have been stumbling with `java.io.InvalidClassException: org.apache.commons.lang3.time.FastDateParser` lately, trying to solve it with no avail.

My current workspace consists of Talend Studio 7.3.1 patch R2020-09, executing on a remote cluster with Cloudera Hadoop 6.3.2 (Spark ver 2.4.0).

Following the stack trace:

```
org.apache.spark.SparkException: Job aborted.
at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.FileFormatWriter$.write(FileFormatWriter.scala:198)
at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.InsertIntoHadoopFsRelationCommand.run(InsertIntoHadoopFsRelationCommand.scala:159)
at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.command.DataWritingCommandExec.sideEffectResult$lzycompute(commands.scala:104)
at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.command.DataWritingCommandExec.sideEffectResult(commands.scala:102)
at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.command.DataWritingCommandExec.doExecute(commands.scala:122)
at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.SparkPlan$$anonfun$execute$1.apply(SparkPlan.scala:131)
at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.SparkPlan$$anonfun$execute$1.apply(SparkPlan.scala:127)
at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.SparkPlan$$anonfun$executeQuery$1.apply(SparkPlan.scala:155)
at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDDOperationScope$.withScope(RDDOperationScope.scala:151)
at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.SparkPlan.executeQuery(SparkPlan.scala:152)
at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.SparkPlan.execute(SparkPlan.scala:127)
at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.QueryExecution.toRdd$lzycompute(QueryExecution.scala:80)
at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.QueryExecution.toRdd(QueryExecution.scala:80)
at org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrameWriter$$anonfun$runCommand$1.apply(DataFrameWriter.scala:668)
at org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrameWriter$$anonfun$runCommand$1.apply(DataFrameWriter.scala:668)
at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.SQLExecution$$anonfun$withNewExecutionId$1.apply(SQLExecution.scala:78)
at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.SQLExecution$.withSQLConfPropagated(SQLExecution.scala:125)
at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.SQLExecution$.withNewExecutionId(SQLExecution.scala:73)
at org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrameWriter.runCommand(DataFrameWriter.scala:668)
at org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrameWriter.saveToV1Source(DataFrameWriter.scala:276)
at org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrameWriter.save(DataFrameWriter.scala:270)
at org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrameWriter.save(DataFrameWriter.scala:228)
at org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrameWriter.csv(DataFrameWriter.scala:656)
at ... (private stuff)
Caused by: org.apache.spark.SparkException: Job aborted due to stage failure:
Aborting TaskSet 5.0 because task 6 (partition 6)
cannot run anywhere due to node and executor blacklist.
Most recent failure:
Lost task 4.2 in stage 5.0 (TID 225, slaaeizeba13.enelint.global, executor 4): java.io.InvalidClassException: org.apache.commons.lang3.time.FastDateParser; local class incompatible: stream classdesc serialVersionUID = 2, local class serialVersionUID = 3
at java.io.ObjectStreamClass.initNonProxy(ObjectStreamClass.java:616)
at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readNonProxyDesc(ObjectInputStream.java:1843)
at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readClassDesc(ObjectInputStream.java:1713)
at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readOrdinaryObject(ObjectInputStream.java:2000)
at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readObject0(ObjectInputStream.java:1535)
at java.io.ObjectInputStream.defaultReadFields(ObjectInputStream.java:2245)
at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readSerialData(ObjectInputStream.java:2169)
at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readOrdinaryObject(ObjectInputStream.java:2027)
at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readObject0(ObjectInputStream.java:1535)
at java.io.ObjectInputStream.defaultReadFields(ObjectInputStream.java:2245)
at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readSerialData(ObjectInputStream.java:2169)
at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readOrdinaryObject(ObjectInputStream.java:2027)
at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readObject0(ObjectInputStream.java:1535)
at java.io.ObjectInputStream.defaultReadFields(ObjectInputStream.java:2245)
at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readSerialData(ObjectInputStream.java:2169)
at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readOrdinaryObject(ObjectInputStream.java:2027)
at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readObject0(ObjectInputStream.java:1535)
at java.io.ObjectInputStream.defaultReadFields(ObjectInputStream.java:2245)
at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readSerialData(ObjectInputStream.java:2169)
at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readOrdinaryObject(ObjectInputStream.java:2027)
at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readObject0(ObjectInputStream.java:1535)
at java.io.ObjectInputStream.defaultReadFields(ObjectInputStream.java:2245)
at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readSerialData(ObjectInputStream.java:2169)
at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readOrdinaryObject(ObjectInputStream.java:2027)
at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readObject0(ObjectInputStream.java:1535)
at java.io.ObjectInputStream.defaultReadFields(ObjectInputStream.java:2245)
at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readSerialData(ObjectInputStream.java:2169)
at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readOrdinaryObject(ObjectInputStream.java:2027)
at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readObject0(ObjectInputStream.java:1535)
at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readObject(ObjectInputStream.java:422)
at org.apache.spark.serializer.JavaDeserializationStream.readObject(JavaSerializer.scala:75)
at org.apache.spark.serializer.JavaSerializerInstance.deserialize(JavaSerializer.scala:114)
at org.apache.spark.scheduler.ResultTask.runTask(ResultTask.scala:83)
at org.apache.spark.scheduler.Task.run(Task.scala:121)
at org.apache.spark.executor.Executor$TaskRunner$$anonfun$11.apply(Executor.scala:407)
at org.apache.spark.util.Utils$.tryWithSafeFinally(Utils.scala:1408)
at org.apache.spark.executor.Executor$TaskRunner.run(Executor.scala:413)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
```

This only happens on the `.csv` method, which is located inside a `tFileOutputDelimeted` component. We generate these CSV to move data to a Redshift database afterwards.

**Upon investigating, the `hive-exec-2.1.1-cdh6.3.2` jar contains a FastDateParser (inside it's own `commons-lang3` implementation) with serialVersionUID = 2, while the `commons-lang3-3.7` jar contains a FastDateParser with serialVersionUID = 3.**

What I've tried so far:

- Changing the CSV compression format.
- Establishing a custom Spark serializer in the Spark configuration.
- Explicitly adding a dependency to `commons-lang3-3.7` and `hive-exec-2.1.1-cdh6.3.2` while excluding `commons-lang3` from the latter in the Standalone Job pom (Project Settings > Build > Maven > Default > Standalone Job)
- Adding the code of the answer of this question [commons-lang3 invalid versions in cloudera 6.1 with spark 2.4](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54504972/commons-lang3-invalid-versions-in-cloudera-6-1-with-spark-2-4) in the same place

Anything I can do to avoid this issue **without upgrading to a new patch?**

Any help would be great. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

edit pom.xml

```
  <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.commons</groupId>
            <artifactId>commons-lang3</artifactId>
            <version>3.12.0</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.hive</groupId>
            <artifactId>hive-exec</artifactId>
            <version>${hive.version}</version>
</dependency>
```

put `commons-lang3` ahead

Comment: Did not seem to do the trick. I still get the error every now and then, it doesn't even show the library on the YARN logs.